# Images are not overflow:hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css

i need to my images overflow each for my slideshow but it not overflowed

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#slider {
  position:relative;
}
.owl-carousel .images {
  overflow:hidden;
   min-width:960px;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}
.owl-carousel img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  }
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="images">
       <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/1.jpg" alt="">
         <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/2.jpg" alt="">
           <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/3.jpg" alt="">
             <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/4.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

any one suggest me with some code for slideshow to run auto

Comment: you can check fancy box http://fancybox.net/

Comment: Go with owl carousel 2 slider..It has more js functions...Its still in beta but more useful

Comment: no need to use plugins..i suggest create your own..do you want image to be in one row on next to other

Comment: did you properly referenced the owl js file in your page?

Comment: yes thats what i need . and also need auto play on page load with some timer manner

Comment: i am not using owl carousel plugin i need to create my own with jquery code to run auto and hover pause

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: before using jquery i have problem with my overflow concept images not overflowing . any suggestion with css styling

Comment: have you tried overlow:hidden on the parent element?

Comment: i just update my code still same problem

Comment: perhaps you miss a semi-colon **;** on the property overflow

Comment: yeah i was : ) in hurry. works now. but another problem arrises. images not showing full ?? how about that

Comment: can you post your js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this :

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#slider {
  position:relative;
}
.owl-carousel .images {
 
   min-width:960px;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}
.owl-carousel img {
position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  }
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="images">
       <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/1.jpg" alt="">
         <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/2.jpg" alt="">
           <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/3.jpg" alt="">
             <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/4.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: i post new question with jquery added pls find and help on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36351428/jquery-slideshow-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo at:

```
.owl-carousel .images {
  overflow:hidden
  min-width:960px;
```

Add semicolon:

```
.owl-carousel .images {
  overflow:hidden;
  min-width:960px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its an minor mistek semicolon not there,

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#slider {
  position:relative;
}
.owl-carousel .images {
  overflow:hidden;
   min-width:960px;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}
.owl-carousel img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  }
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="images">
       <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/1.jpg" alt="">
         <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/2.jpg" alt="">
           <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/3.jpg" alt="">
             <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/4.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```