# Jquery Slideshow Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have create a  simple slideshow but its not working.
i have used function and setInterval but still cant see any effect.
also any mistake  on **css selector**

```js
function slideshow() {
      var $active = $('DIV#slider-wrap IMG.active');
      var $next = $active.next();
      $next.addClass('active');
      $active.removeClass('active');
     }
     $(function(){
         setInterval("slideshow",5000);
     });
```

```css
    * {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
    } 
    #slider-wrap {
     position:relative;
    }
    .slideshow .images {
     width:100%;
     max-width:960px;
     height:350px;
     overflow:hidden;
    }
    .slideshow .images img {
                 position:absolute;
                 width:100%;
                 max-width:960px;
                 height:auto;
    }
    .active {
     z-index:99;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider-wrap">
      <div class="slideshow">
          <div class="images">
    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/1.jpg" alt="" class="active">
    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/4.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
      </div> 
  </div>
```

help me out on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

javascript [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) accepts as first argument a function and not a string.

```js
function slideshow() {
  var $active = $('div#slider-wrap img.active');
  var $next = $active.next();
  $next.addClass('active');
  $active.removeClass('active');
}
$(function() {
  setInterval(slideshow, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#slider-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.slideshow .images {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: 350px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slideshow .images img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
}
.active {
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider-wrap">
  <div class="slideshow">
    <div class="images">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/1.jpg" alt="" class="active">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/2.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/3.jpg" alt="">
      <img src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/images/4.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks buddy. its working fine now. many many thanks. can use pre and next controll can u make that ?